# Will uploading iPhone X screenshots to App Store Connect prevent 5.5" screenshots showing in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store, screenshot, app-store-connect

So, I couldn't find an answer to this easily, but here's the longer version of the question.

As iPhone X screenshots are optional, iPhone Xs will use the 5.5" screenshots in the App Store if none are available. However if I add just one screenshot for iPhone X, will they still show the 5.5" pictures as well?  or will the App Store now show just that one image?

On a similar vein, am I correct in thinking that I need to upload a preview video separately for both iPad and iPhone, or can I use the same video for both?

Comment: Well, uploading just 1 screen shot for iPhone X is a matter of experimentation. How will apple treat this scenario? The testers are individuals and may treat your case differently. They will either discard the lonely screen shot and accept the app or  may reply to you with a concern. One of my apps got accepted with a slight mistake in screen shots, but on next version they noticed the problem and asked me to fix it. My personal suggestion would be to upload all 5.

Comment: @Asim Thanks for the response. My issue is Apple recommends adding X screenshots, but I don't have access to a physical iPhone X, only the simulator. Normally this would be fine but in my case the game runs very laggy on the simulators, making them very bad to try to get screenshots or videos. I'm thinking I may just skip out X shots altogether

Comment: My company does it via Sketch or Photoshop and make sure it's the right size.. They don't actually screenshot our app on the device itself..

Comment: @Brandon Ah okay, I like that idea. Then instead of hoping I get a good distribution (game is based heavily on random numbers) I can just forcibly make it so. Thanks for the suggestion! Although doesn't solve the video problem